# How to find the minimum value of cos(2x)+cos(4x)+cos(6x)+cos(8x)+...+cos(20x)

Tags: trigonometric-series

I want to find the minimum value of the series cos(2x)+cos(4x)+cos(6x)+cos(8x)+...+cos(2nx). x could be 2*pi*t. Anyone can share a method of how to determine the minimum value of the series?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Just take the derivative and find the critical points would be okay?

Comment: You can isolate sin(x) and find the critical points associated with sin(x), but not sure whether those critical points for sin(x) could lead to the minimum value.

Comment: @DaveDu - differentiate the function again (ie, 2nd derivative) and check the values at critical points. If the second derivative is positive, the point would give minima. (I'd expect summation of cosine to n terms to form continuous function). Alternatively, you can first shorten your summation using the [cosine summation identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro) when terms are in A.P

Comment: Last term is $\cos(20x)$ or $\cos(2nx)$?

Comment: let's say 2nx in order to be generic. Want to know the method of determining the minimum value.

Comment: @SteelCubes - It's not so easy to get the critical points. Please show me how to get the critical points step by step if you have worked it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1} \cos(kx)=R\left(\sum_{k=1} e^{2ikx}\right)$

Comment: You can find the sum by doing this way, but the question is how to determine the minimum value.

Answer (score 2):

Comment:

Let $t=2x$ , you get:

$s=\cos (t)+\cos(2t)+\cos(3t)+\cdot\cdot\cdot +\cos(10t)$

Now use this formula:

$$s=\cos (t)+\cos(2t)+\cos(3t)+\cdot\cdot\cdot +\cos(nt)=\frac{\sin \frac n2 t\cos\frac {n+1}2 t}{\sin (\frac t 2)}$$

So you have to find minimum of this function:

$$y=\frac{\sin(10x)\cos(11x)}{\sin(x)}$$

By plotting in Wolfram minimum of y is about -2.8.

Comment: Finding the sum is easy. The difficult part is to take the derivative and equate it to zero in order to find the critical points. Could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: No doubt that the maximum value is 10, but the minimum value is -2.78 by plotting the graph. The reasoning for minimum value is not correct.

Comment: I plotted in wolfram and it can be seen that max and min are equal in absolute value although not for a certain value of x. minimum , due to wolfram plot is certainly less than -2.78.it looks less than 3 for sure.

Comment: Sorry I am looking for the minimum value for $x$ =\pi $t$, then it will be periodic for $t$ in [0,1] and the minimum value is around -2.78. But really this should not be matter and the minimum value should not change. Your sum expression is not correct. The cos(21$x$) should be cos(11$x$) for $n$ = 10.

Comment: -10 can't be the minimum value as there is no such x that can let all the individual item equate -1 simultaneously as their frequency is different.

Comment: @DaveDu, thanks for pointing out my error. I corrected it. I will submit the plot by Wolfram.You can also plot it in Wolfram and see the curve is symmetric about x axis.

Comment: @DaveDu, You are write . I plotted the corrected function and minimum is about                                                                                         -2.78. It is interest to know how this was found analytically.

Comment: it is not easy to take the derivative and let it equate $0$ in order to find the critical points.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE. As a hint, you might want to look into [Lagrange's trignometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange%27s_trigonometric_identities). (They can be derived with complex numbers like Luis is suggesting.